# Rio functions in server-client API

Tags: c, server

When I write between my server and my client, I make use of the rio functions (specified in the csapp.c), more specifically:

```
Rio_writen --> when writing to a socket
Rio_readlineb --> when reading from a socket
```

My problem is that whenever I send information from e.g. my client to my server, example:

```
Rio_writen(name_server_socket, "null", 4);
Rio_writen(name_server_socket, "\n", 1);
```

I expect my server when calling:

```
Rio_readlineb(&rio, name, MAXLINE); 
char* lookup = name;
assert(lookup == "null"); --> fail
assert(strcmp(lookup, "null") == 0); --> fail
```

To assert that the message is equivalent to "null". However, when I use prints to show my messages on either site, this is what I get:

```
// client side message send
lookup_name: (null)|

// server side message received
lookup_name: (null)
|
```

I use the | character to see if anything is added after my message is sent (by printf("x: %s|",something)). In this case every message I sent get a newline character at the end, and I do not understand why.

Using the rio function, in particular Rio_getlineb to read inputs: it reads until it reaches the end of the line (provided a newline character). Thus, I'm expected to provide a newline character at the end of any message I sent (hence why i do (*Rio_writen(name_server_socket, "\n", 1);*) after each message sent).

Can anyone see what I am missing (or in any case know a solution to the problem)? All my setups are working correctly: sockets, rio_t etc. The messages are sent and received, but somehow add a newline at the end.

EDIT: The assertion is just a placeholder for doing something with the data. So adding a newline to the assertion might solve the assert, but not my problem: which is why a newline is added in the first place :-) My point is that I want to parse the "lookup" to a function that compares that value to a name, given in  a struct. So I cannot just add a newline to the struct->name that I am looking at.

Comment: `assert(lookup == "null");` --> `assert(strcmp(lookup, "null") == 0);`

Comment: @DavidRanieri Yeah I tried that also :) still not working because of the fact that a newline is somehow added at the receiving site of the message. (see the above example on received message print)

Comment: Then  `assert(strcmp(lookup, "null\n") == 0);` to include the newline.

Comment: @DavidRanieri also tried. the problem is that I want to act on the server site dependent on what information its provided with. Thus the assert here is just a simple placeholder for doing something with the data. My problem is I do not understand why a newline character is added at the receiving end upon using rio_readlineb.

Comment: `Rio_writen(name_server_socket, "\n", 1);` That explicitly writes a newline. So why is it surprising that the reading end sees a newline?

Comment: @kaylum the rio_readlineb terminates after a newline character is found. That means if I do not provide a newline character it just continues to read. In order words I would not expect rio_readlineb to include the newline, as it terminates at the newline character and returns.

Comment: I believe your expectation is wrong. It does store the newline. I'm not that familiar with your course but a web search shows the `rio_readlineb` implementation [here](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/2e/ch10-preview.pdf). It clearly shows the newline is stored: `*bufp++ = c; if (c == ’\n’) break;`. That is, `c` is stored before checking for newline.

Comment: @kaylum That might be true, I was told otherwise when I chose to use this approach, that is to explicitly include a newline character message to ensure the termination is correct.

Comment: Yes you need to include a newline for termination. But that doesn't mean that the newline isn't included in the read. In fact, I guessed straight away without looking at the code that it likely does include the newline because that's how the standard C function [`fgets`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) works which `rio_readlineb` is mirroring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I see in the documentation:

> – rio_readlineb reads a text line of up to maxlen bytes from file fd
>   and stores the line in usrbuf
>
> - Especially useful for reading text lines from network sockets
>
> – Stopping conditions
>
> - maxlen bytes read
> - EOF encountered
> - Newline (‘ \n ’) encountered

That is, the same as `fgets` does.

And looking at the source code:

```
/* $begin rio_readlineb */
ssize_t rio_readlineb(rio_t *rp, void *usrbuf, size_t maxlen) 
{
    int n, rc;
    char c, *bufp = usrbuf;

    for (n = 1; n < maxlen; n++) { 
        if ((rc = rio_read(rp, &c, 1)) == 1) {
        *bufp++ = c;
        if (c == '\n') {
            n++;
            break;
        }
```

It includes the trailing newline in the buffer.

This newline is very useful, the fact that the message does not include it is an indication that you have not read the whole line (in your case received the entire package), in which case you can continue requesting data.

What we usually do with `fgets` to skip the trailing newline is:

```
char *ptr = strchr(lookup, '\n');

if (ptr != NULL)
{
    *ptr = '\0'; // Replace newline with NUL
}
```

Comment: Yeah I see that now, I just took my mentors word for good when I was told to explicitly include it when sending a message. I will try the approach you show below, that is actually a great idea thanks! Does the ptr update the lookup directly?

Comment: David ignore above, I can see it does when implementing, This is great thanks!